# iOS In App Purchase subscription - change appleid

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My app has not login function. So it does not has it's own user system.
When user buy a subscription in My app, then he changes his apple id in iPhone's setting. How my app know user change his apple id and does not give him rights to view purchased content?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
EveryTime enter app, refresh receipt, then vertify the receipt.